# how can I design custom action bar for android app

Tags: android-actionbar

I'm going to design action bar like this in my app

[image]

how can I do it?

Comment: This question doesn't show any research effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**STEP 1.** Make an XML layout like this:

**my_custom_actionbar_layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        android:background="darkgreen"
        android:text = "Back"
        android:textColor = "#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/center_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Place"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/map_button"
        android:background="darkgreen"
        android:text = "Map"
        android:textColor = "#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the above layout, you must specify the hex color code for the dark green color you want to use (i.e. in `android:background="darkgreen"` you must replace `darkgreen` with the hex color code you want). The `ActionBar`'s background color will be specified below.

**STEP 2.** In the `onCreate()` of your all your `ActionBarActivity` classes, put the following code:

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,     ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
View actionBarView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.my_custom_actionbar_layout, null); 
actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView, lp);
```

**NOTE:** If you are only supporting API level 11+ and therefore using `Activity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`, then in the above code replace:

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

with

```
android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
```

**STEP 3.** Add the following code to all your `Activity` classes:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    return false;
}
```

**STEP 4.** In your `res/values` folder, define an XML file `theme.xml` and add the following to it:

```
<resources  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="DefaultActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:targetApi="11">@style/MyActionBar</item> 
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item> 
        <item name="android:actionBarSize" tools:targetApi="11">@dimen/action_bar_wrap_content</item> 
        <item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/action_bar_wrap_content</item> 
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background" tools:targetApi="11">@color/actionbarbgcolor</item> 
        <item name="background">@color/actionbarbgcolor</item>
        <item name="android:height" tools:targetApi="11">@dimen/action_bar_wrap_content</item>
        <item name="height">@dimen/action_bar_wrap_content</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

In the same folder make another XML file `colors.xml` and add the following to it:

```
<resources>
    <color
        name="actionbarbgcolor">#00FF00
    </color>
</resources>
```

and to the existing file `dimens.xml`, add the last line:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

    <!-- Optional, in case you wish to increase the default width of the Action Bar. -->
    <dimen name="action_bar_wrap_content">55dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

In place of `#00FF00` above, use the hex color code for the light green color you have used in your image.

**NOTE:** The above will work assuming you are using the `appcompat-v7` library. If not, then you'll have to use one of the `Holo.Light` themes instead of `AppCompat.Light`, and there will be other changes as well.

**STEP 5.** In your manifest file, you must add:

```
android:theme="@style/DefaultActionBarTheme"
```

to every `<activity` declaration if that `Activity` has the `ActionBar`.

Try this. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Following this tutorial (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground), you can change the background of the Action Bar of your application, using a simple drawable.

Then, you also can add widgets to it, in order to get the same result as above (old iOS design ?).